# Unable to build apk due to cannot find symbol picasso.fit();

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, picasso

I am trying to build APK with cordova build android command but error occured during build and build can't be generated. The error is with PICASSO library.  Please find all the relevant details below. **Ionic info:**

```
 Ionic:
 ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.8.0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
 Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
 @ionic/v1-toolkit : not installed
 Cordova:
 cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
 Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0
 Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 19 
 other plugins)

 System:

 Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/user/Android/Sdk)
 NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/bin/node)
 npm               : 5.6.0
 OS                : Linux 4.15
```

platforms/android/com-sarriaroman-photoviewer/abc123photoviewer.gradle has following code

```
repositories{
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
implementaion 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
implementaion 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
android {

}
```

Hence the error

```
    BUILD FAILED in 3s
38 actionable tasks: 36 executed, 2 up-to-date
/var/www/projects/ionic_practice/test/app_mobile_new/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/var/www/projects/ionic_practice/test/app_mobile_new/platforms/android/src/com/sarriaroman/PhotoViewer/PhotoActivity.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
            picasso.fit();
                   ^
  symbol:   method fit()
  location: variable picasso of type Picasso
/var/www/projects/ionic_practice/test/app_mobile_new/platforms/android/src/com/sarriaroman/PhotoViewer/PhotoActivity.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
            picasso.centerInside();
                   ^
  symbol:   method centerInside()
  location: variable picasso of type Picasso
/var/www/projects/ionic_practice/test/app_mobile_new/platforms/android/src/com/sarriaroman/PhotoViewer/PhotoActivity.java:179: error: cannot find symbol
            picasso.centerCrop();
                   ^
  symbol:   method centerCrop()
  location: variable picasso of type Picasso
/var/www/projects/ionic_practice/test/app_mobile_new/platforms/android/src/com/sarriaroman/PhotoViewer/PhotoActivity.java:200: error: cannot find symbol
                    .into(photo, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    ^
  symbol:   method into(ImageView,<anonymous Callback>)
  location: class Picasso
/var/www/projects/ionic_practice/test/app_mobile_new/platforms/android/src/com/sarriaroman/PhotoViewer/PhotoActivity.java:224: error: cannot find symbol
                    Piccasso picasso = Picasso.with(PhotoActivity.this)
                    ^
  symbol: class Piccasso
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
5 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Maybe just a simple Mistyping? shouldn't `Piccasso picasso = Picasso..` have only one "c"? (Piccasso)

Comment: Id say the same thing check the spelling of that's not it then the only other thing I could guess would be some hope it isn't getting implemented right.  But spelling is most probable cause

Comment: @Vahalaru I changed to Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(PhotoActivity.this) but still same error. Following is the error now 
`error: incompatible types: RequestCreator cannot be converted to Picasso
                            .load(mTempImage);` @Kaddath

Comment: I actually don't know Picasso and how to implement it in Ionic, just seen what seemed to be a typo. You might need to add the code so that other people can help (we don't see where `RequestCreator` and `Picasso.load` are called)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an issue with the version 1.20 of the plugin.

You can use 1.1.18 and it works well with that.

Here is how to move to 1.1.18

```
$ ionic cordova plugin rm com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
$ ionic cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer@1.1.18
```

Build and it will work

```
cordova build android 

...
...
...
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:packageDebug
:app:assembleDebug
:app:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 32s
46 actionable tasks: 46 executed
```

If this still gives you the same error as earlier, try removing the android platform once and adding it again,

```
$ cordova platform rm android

$ cordova platform add android
```

Comment: By running the above commands, I am able to generate the APK. Thanks for pointing out the exact solution. The correct version for photoviewer is 1.1.18. 
Thanks, Cheers.

Comment: I tried but its not accepting due to less reputation. What should i do now @Mayank R Jain

Comment: Hi there! Once plugin is removed, don't we also need to uninstall it using "npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/photo-viewer"?

Comment: The solution worked for me. 1. Plugin remove; 2. Plugin add @1.1.18; 3. Platform remove; 4. Platform add;

Comment: Does anyone tried with the v1.2.1? Perhaps the problem has been solved...

Answer (score 1):

This is to confirm that the issue with the version 1.20 of the plugin is solved on the latest version : 1.2.4

Here is how to move to the latest

```
$ ionic cordova plugin rm com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
$ ionic cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.2.5 solves this

```
ionic cordova plugin rm com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
ionic cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
```